# How to create Adobe Air Internet Radio?

Tags: adobe, air, flash-cs5, adobe-flash-cs3

I am going to develop Adobe Air Internet Radio. I have knowledge of designing of Adobe Air application & also I found  [SHOUTcast Radio Directory API](http://wiki.winamp.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_Radio_Directory_API) but I dont know how to use it. Can any one please suggest hints how to use in application. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create am HTMLLoader object, and load it with the appropriate URL.  From [the Adobe docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_02.html#1040817):

```
var container:Sprite;
var html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader;
html.width = 400;
html.height = 600;
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com/");
html.load(urlReq);
container.addChild(html);
```